# How to combine an older Time Machine backup with a newer one

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a client who was using a certain external drive as their Time Machine drive for a while. Then, they misplaced it. So, they got a new external drive and started using *that*. Now, they've found the original Time Machine drive, and would like to combine the backup from the *old* drive to the *new* one.

From the looks of it, the folder for each backup job in Time Machine contains *all* files from the Mac. Even though it's supposed to be an incremental backup, the "unchanged" files appear in each folder, but they're just hard-links to pre-existing copies on the Time Machine drive (Dirvish, on Linux, behaves this way, too, incidentally).

I have seen suggestions that, to combine the backups, you can just copy the old backup folders to the new drive, but this will waste spaces, as hard-links won't be created when I copy over a file from the old drive which already exists on the new one.

So, it seems that what is needed is a tool which, for each file being copied over to the new drive, will check to see if it's identical to any of the pre-existing versions and, if so, make a hard-link to that pre-existing file instead of creating a new one.

Is there already a tool out there for doing this? Or, is there something else about the process that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd seriously ask them why they'd want to do this. Do they anticipate needing to go back in time so far to recover a version of a file like that? The new TM drive contains a backup of everything like the old drive, it just doesn't have the ancient history on it.

Comment: I agree with Ian C. in questioning the point of this. You may be able to do so using a third external drive, at the cost of possibly damaging either/both backups. See [How Can I Copy My TM Backups to a Different Location](http://pondini.org/TM/18.html#id11)

Comment: Then you're questioning the point of anybody keeping anything but the most-recent backup of anything. The reason they want this is because they sometimes want to retrieve documents that they deleted some time ago. This client isn't an organized person, I admit. But I also assert that "You shouldn't want to do this" isn't a solution.